# InvalidPathException when integrating Apache Jena into Web Application project

Tags: maven, jena

I want to use Jena inside a JSF Web Application.

My `pom.xml` contains the depencency for `jena-arq` version `3.9.0` and dependencies for JSF.

I have created an `IndexView` backing Bean with an `init` method, annotated with `@PostConstruct`. 
Everything works fine without calling Jena API.
On adding to `init` method this simple line
`OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);`
these exception are thrown:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
...
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file:location-mapping.rdf
```

I've tried to change the Jena version used with an older version and I've noticed that until version `2.11.0` everything works. With newer versions the above exceptions are thrown.

It seems that the `file:` prefix is the problem. I've found this related topic [link](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-889) but it says that the bug has been fixed.

Comment: Which is the latest version of Jena you have tried? It would also be helpful to see the stack to see where the exception is coming from within Jena.

Comment: I've tried all versions of Jena backwards from 3.10.0 until I found a working version (2.11.0). These are the links of my [test repository](https://github.com/agleoni/ProvaMaven) and [stacktrace](https://github.com/agleoni/ProvaMaven/blob/master/stacktrace.txt)

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace shows that classloader is specific to the environment - it is calling `org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` which is probably why code that has not changed in many versions does not work here.

Why this classloader is throwing `InvalidPathException` from the filesystem when it is a *classloader* is strange and different behaviour to the standard Java OpenJDK (`getResourceAsStream` returns null for `file:location-mapping.rdf`).

If you don't need files remapped, you try adding a call disable this feature:

```
import org.apache.jena.util.LocationMapper;
```

(note there are two classes called "LocationMapper")

and use the call:

```
LocationMapper.setGlobalLocationMapper(new LocationMapper());
```

This must be called very early, before any other Jena code.

Comment: I've tried adding this line before calling `createOntModel()` and I've modified stacktrace of my repo beacuse is throwing a new exception:
`Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file:ont-policy.rdf`

Comment: Same exception? Just not in an initializer now? The call has to be before any Jena call in the system - that can include class due to classloading and initialization.